# Doctrine: MappingException on server, working localy

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Im having this weird issue with doctrine: Im working on an old project using Symfony (3.4.49)

I have to create a new table on its database so I also created a new Entity class, called App\Entity\PayrollPayRulesDefault, on src/Entity, with all other entities

On my local environment, it just worked. But when I pushed it to the staging server to test, it just wont:

```
 request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException: "The class 'App\Entity\PayrollPayRulesDefault' was not found in the chain configured namespaces " at /var/app/current/vendor/doctrine/persistence/lib/Doctrine/Persistence/Mapping/MappingException.php line 23 {"exception":"[object] (Doctrine\\Persistence\\Mapping\\MappingException(code: 0): The class 'App\\Entity\\PayrollPayRulesDefault' was not found in the chain configured namespaces  at /var/app/current/vendor/doctrine/persistence/lib/Doctrine/Persistence/Mapping/MappingException.php:23)"} []
```

Doctrine config is exactly the same for both envirmoments:

```
# config/packages/doctrine.yaml
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: project
        connections:
            project:
                # configure these for your database server
                url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
                driver: 'pdo_mysql'
                server_version: '5.7'
                charset: utf8mb4
            messagequeue:
                # configure these for your database server
                url: '%env(resolve:MESSAGING_QUEUE_URL)%'
                driver: 'pdo_mysql'
                server_version: '5.7'
                charset: utf8mb4
    orm:
        default_entity_manager: project
        entity_managers:
            project:
                connection: project
                mappings:
                    App:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity'
                        alias: App
            messagequeue:
                connection: messagequeue
                mappings:
                    MessageQueue:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/MessageQueue'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity\MessageQueue'
                        alias: MessageQueue
```

The entity class itself seems correct:

```
namespace App\Entity;

use App\Entity\Component\EntityComponent;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * PayrollPayRulesDefault
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="payroll_pay_rules_default", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="ruleSubType", columns={"ruleSubType"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class PayrollPayRulesDefault extends EntityComponent
{
```

I tried clearing the cache:

```
php bin/console cache:clear
php bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata
```

Tried warming it up too:

```
php bin/console cache:warmup
```

Also tried just deleting the cache directory too: nothing changes

Im dont have a lot of experience with symfony, but, from what I can tell, the project  configuration seems correct. And is the same on my local server, where it works

So I dont know what to try or investigate anymore. Please help, this is driving me crazy

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I was able to fix it myself finally.

```
php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod

php bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata --env=prod

php bin/console cache:warmup --env=prod --no-debug

php bin/console doctrine:mapping:info --env=prod
```